# Accessing HTTP headers in ISAPI Rewrite 3

Tags: isapi-rewrite

Is there any way to access HTTP headers in ISAPI_Rewrite module? Didn't find anything about it. I know IIS URL Rewrite allows you to access headers as server variables - {HTTP_HEADER_NAME} - is there something similar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, nevermind...

Missed a line in a documentation:

> HTTP header value with the syntax %{HTTP:header}.

http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteCond.htm